# What would be the SwiftUI way to make "page curl" animation on button tap?

Tags: ios, swiftui

So I want to make a "page curl"-like animation in response to a button tap in the app made with SwiftUI
So far the only solution I have found is to use UIPageViewController, which seems to be a somewhat inelegant solution.
Is there some better way to make custom animations? Something akin to `withAnimation(.default)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this animation tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV9ybRJpuB8.

It can be used with Tabs in a TabView to reproduce a page curling event.
You might have to use layers in a ForEach - ZTSack, instead of a list.

I think a UIPageViewController representable is also a good solution.

**Edit:**
A PageViewController is not a bad option for what you want to achieve. There is no such animation modifier but you can add pages as modifiers.

```
struct Pager: View {
    // Here we add pages using a modifier for each new view
    var body: some View {
        PageRepresentable()
            .addPage {
                PageContent {
                    AnyView(
                        Text("Hello")
                    )
                }
            }
            .addPage {
                PageContent {
                    AnyView(
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                    )
                }
            }
            .addPage {
                PageContent {
                    AnyView(
                        Text("Last")
                    )
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
// The Content will be the view we want to insert into a     UIHostViewController    
struct PageContent<Content: View>: View {

    var pageContent: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder pageContent: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.pageContent = pageContent()
    }
    var body: some View {
        pageContent
    }
}


struct PageRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = PagerController

    @State var pages: [PageContent<AnyView>] = []

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PagerController {
        PagerController(pages: pages)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PagerController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.pages = pages.map {
            UIHostingController(rootView: $0)
        }
    }
}

extension PageRepresentable {
// We get the current pager, update the state and return one with an updated state. Then we can use this method as modifier since its an extension
    func addPage(@ViewBuilder page: @escaping () -> PageContent<AnyView>) -> PageRepresentable {
        let pager = self
        var pages = pager.pages
        pages.append(page())
        return PageRepresentable(pages: pages)
    }
}
    
class PagerController: UIPageViewController {

    private var currentIndex: Int = 0
// When we get our first pages we set the first view controller of our UIPageViewController
    var pages: [UIHostingController<PageContent<AnyView>>] = [] {
        willSet {
            if pages.isEmpty && !newValue.isEmpty {
                setViewControllers([newValue.first!], direction: .forward, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    private func isIndexOk(_ index: Int) -> Bool {
        pages.count > index && index >= 0
    }

    init() {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        dataSource = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension PagerController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let nexIndex = currentIndex + 1
        guard isIndexOk(nexIndex) else { return nil }
        self.currentIndex = nexIndex
        let next = pages[currentIndex]
        return next
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let nexIndex = currentIndex - 1
        guard isIndexOk(nexIndex) else { return nil }
        self.currentIndex = nexIndex
        let next = pages[currentIndex]
        return next
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this tutorial does not produce a "page turned by the corner" effect, which i would like to have. Is there some kind of modifier that can add a curled "angle" to that "page" layer?

Comment: @Dmytro.
I don't think so, but you can create builder pattern that you'll use in a view to add pages to a page controller. Look at the edit. Maybe it will help.